# Can't send E-mail with SendGrid WebApi lib

Tags: c#, sendgrid

Every time that I tried to send an E-mail I get the BadRequest related to a cross-origin. I've tried to search about the problem and it seems like because I'm calling from the browser (localhost) it wont work.
Basically I'm making a Ajax call to my Aspnet mvc and them calling a WebApi project

```
public async Task<Response> SendEmail(string email, string link, string companyName)
    {
        var apiKey = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SMTP");
        var client = new SendGridClient(apiKey);

        var from = new EmailAddress("d.com", "d");
        var subject = "Sending with SendGrid is Fun";
        var to = new EmailAddress(email, "Caro");
        var plainTextContent = "and easy to do anywhere, even with C#";
        var htmlContent = "<strong>Aqui está seu contrato </strong>";
        var msg = MailHelper.CreateSingleEmail(from, to, subject, plainTextContent, htmlContent);
        return await client.SendEmailAsync(msg);

    }
```

That's the response :

> {Server: nginx
>   Date: Tue, 10 Dec 2019 14:17:40 GMT
>   Connection: keep-alive
>   Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://sendgrid.api-docs.io
>   Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST
>   Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization, Content-Type, On-behalf-of, x-sg-elas-acl
>   Access-Control-Max-Age: 600
>   X-No-CORS-Reason: https://sendgrid.com/docs/Classroom/Basics/API/cors.html
>   }

Not sure what to do anymore. Should I add something in the header at the `HttpClient` Class ?

Comment: client.SendEmailAsync(msg) is a response. What does it response?

Comment: @IavorOrlyov I updated the question!

Comment: I can't be sure tho but I would suggest you are missing a sender. Where did you get your apiKey? 

You need to create a Sender in their site and you use this apiKey in your code

Comment: I know. the key is there at the Sendgrid

Comment: Have you confirmed your sender's email

Comment: And also I'm pretty sure "d.com" is not a valid sender since it does not pass the validation for an email

Comment: @IavorOrlyov the code below worked for me, not sure if the problem was the wrong e-mail. Thanks :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 private async Task<string> SendMail(string to, string text)
        {
            try
            {
                var msg = new SendGridMessage();
                msg.SetFrom(new EmailAddress("youremail@email.com", "Your Name"));
                msg.AddTo(to);
                msg.SetSubject("Your subject here");
                msg.AddContent(MimeType.Text, text);
                var client = new SendGridClient("???"); // Your sendgrid client private id here
                var response = await client.SendEmailAsync(msg);
                if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Accepted)
                    return "ok";
                else return "failed"; // not happening ))
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return e.Message;
            }
        }
```